# Unique secret by user for JWT Token on Refresh Token Rotation model

Tags: oauth, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

I'm implementing a Refresh Token Rotation on server using JWT tokens with HmacSHA256 sign.

To improve security refresh tokens are being persisted into database to validate a refresh token was used before on a renew refresh token request. But access tokens are not being stored.

For security reasons if server receives a used RT on renew request, all tokens (access and refresh) should be invalidated.

As a solution to invalidate AC, tokens would be generate using `HmacSHA256` **per user** and not single on server.
That means when server identifier a used RT, It's going to generate a new key for next token signs on that user.

To be clear, I'd like to have a unique secret `HmacSHA256` key persisted by user and for every access request and renew request I'd recovering the key from User and NOT from a config file like.

I've read lot of SO questions and searched on Google, but I didn't found anything like storing the keys by user, only by application.

So I don't know this is a good approach to use.

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems with your proposed solution:

1. If the key is per-user, then in order to validate the token you have to trust the data in that token. That is a security issue, especially because you plan to use symmetric signing. If someone manages to get the key used for user A, then they can take a token from user B, change the user ID, and resign the token. You will accept it as a valid token as the signature will match, even though it's a forged token.
2. The above problem is actually why you shouldn't be using symmetric signing. If someone manages to get hold of your secret they will be able to forge new tokens. You should be using asymmetric signing with private-public keys.
3. It will be very complicated to manage all these per-user keys. Your APIs will need these keys to properly validate access tokens. This means that at all times all your APIs will need access to a database of all your per-user keys.

Comment: On item 1, how it's different from a single token per application? The step that reads the JWT token doesn't relies on parsed information ?
Item 2, ok.
For item 3, if I stored the tokens on database won't t have the same problem?

Comment: In item 1 you will have a bit similar issue if you use symmetric signing, even with one key for all users. That's why you shouldn't be using symmetric signing at all. Whenever you need to rely on any data in the token to verify the signature, you have to be extra careful. E.g., if you check what signature algorithm was used. Still, when there is one key for all users, it is possible to quickly spot any problems (e.g., invalid key ID used in the JWT header). With multiple keys, it will be very hard to spot that someone swapped keys.

Comment: If you store tokens in the database then indeed you will have a similar issue. That is why people use JWTs in the first place — because they can be validated offline. You don't have to call the Authorization Server all the time to check the token validity.